# Can't render this HTML on browser

Tags: html

```
&lt;blockquote style=&quot;margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;blockquote style=&quot;margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;blockquote style=&quot;margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;blockquote style=&quot;margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;blockquote style=&quot;margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;blockquote style=&quot;margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot; style=&quot;&quot;&gt;Dispõe sobre a obrigatoriedade da realização de licitação na modalidade pregão e da dispensa de licitação por pequeno valor, na forma eletrônica, por meio da ferramenta “Licitações-e”, no âmbito da Administração Pública Direta e Indireta do Município de Teresina-PI, e dá outras providências.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;O PREFEITO MUNICIPAL DE TERESINA, Estado do Piauí, no uso das atribuições legais que lhe confere o inciso XXV, do art. 71, da Lei Orgânica do Município, DECRETA:&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;Art. 1º A aquisição de bens e serviços comuns, por todos os órgãos e entidades da Administração Municipal Direta e Indireta, deverá ser precedida de licitação na modalidade pregão, na sua forma eletrônica, a ser realizada por meio da ferramenta “Licitações-e”.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;Parágrafo único. Por razões de conveniência e oportunidade, prevalecendo o interesse público, a modalidade pregão presencial poderá ser adotada, em caráter excepcional, mediante autorização fundamentada do titular do órgão ou entidade da Administração Municipal Direta ou Indireta.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;Art. 2º A aquisição de bens e serviços comuns, por todos os órgãos e entidades da Administração Municipal Direta e Indireta, nas hipóteses de dispensa de licitação, previstas no inciso II, do art. 24, da Lei Federal nº 8.666, de 21 de junho de 1993, será realizada, obrigatoriamente, de forma eletrônica, por meio da ferramenta “Licitações-e”.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;Art. 3º Todas as fases do procedimento licitatório e da dispensa de licitação deverão ser realizadas no sistema eletrônico, sem prejuízo da formalização e registro em processo administrativo e da publicação dos respectivos atos no Diário Oficial do Município - DOM.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;Parágrafo único. Compete à Unidade Orçamentária diretamente interessada a adoção das providências mencionadas no caput deste artigo.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;Art. 4º A Secretaria Municipal de Administração e Recursos Humanos - SEMA fica incumbida de elaborar e aprovar minutas padronizadas de editais e de contratos para aquisição de bens e serviços comuns, que deverão ser utilizadas por todos os órgãos e entidades da Administração Municipal Direta, Autarquias e Fundações.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;Art. 5º A Secretaria Municipal de Administração e Recursos Humanos - SEMA promoverá a capacitação dos pregoeiros e das equipes de apoio, dos órgãos e entidades da Administração Municipal Direta, Autarquias e Fundações, e dará suporte técnico e operacional para utilização da ferramenta “Licitações-e”.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;Art. 6º Este Decreto entra em vigor na data de sua publicação.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;Art. 7º Revogam-se as disposições em contrário.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;Gabinete do Prefeito Municipal de Teresina (PI), em 5 de julho de 2017.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;FIRMINO DA SILVEIRA SOARES FILHO&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;Prefeito de Teresina&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: &amp;quot;times new roman&amp;quot;; font-size: medium;&quot;&gt;CHARLES CARVALHO CAMILLO DA SILVEIRA&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;3&quot; face=&quot;times new roman&quot; style=&quot;&quot;&gt;Secretário Municipal de Governo&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

I would like to know how to render this piece of HTML code in my browser. This is what I've done: I opened a text editor and saved the text as .html with ANSI option. When I click on the file, it opens the browser with the content following this convention:

```
<blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;"><blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;"><blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;"><blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;"><blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;"><blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;"><div style="text-align: justify;"><font size="3" face="times new roman" style="">Dispõe sobre a obrigatoriedade da realização de licitação na modalidade pregão e da dispensa de licitação por pequeno valor, na forma eletrônica, por meio da ferramenta “Licitações-e”, no âmbito da Administração Pública Direta e Indireta do Município de Teresina-PI, e dá outras providências.</font></div></blockquote></blockquote></blockquote></blockquote></blockquote></blockquote><div style="text-align: justify;"><font size="3" face="times new roman"><br></font></div><div style="text-align: justify;"><font size="3" face="times new roman"><br></font></div><div style="text-align: left;"><font size="3" face="times new roman">O PREFEITO MUNICIPAL DE TERESINA, Estado do Piauí, no uso das atribuições legais que lhe confere o inciso XXV, do art. 71, da Lei Orgânica do Município, DECRETA:&nbsp;</font></div><div style="text-align: left;"><font size="3" face="times new roman"><br></font></div><div style="text-align: left;"><font size="3" face="times new roman">Art. 1º A aquisição de bens e serviços comuns, por todos os órgãos e entidades da Administração Municipal Direta e Indireta, deverá ser precedida de licitação na modalidade pregão, na sua forma eletrônica, a ser realizada por meio da ferramenta “Licitações-e”.&nbsp;</font></div><div style="text-align: left;"><font size="3" face="times new roman"><br></font></div><div style="text-align: left;"><font size="3" face="times new roman">Parágrafo único. Por razões de conveniência e oportunidade, prevalecendo o interesse público, a modalidade pregão presencial poderá ser adotada, em caráter excepcional, mediante autorização fundamentada do titular do órgão ou entidade da Administração Municipal Direta ou Indireta.&nbsp;</font></div><div style="text-align: left;"><font size="3" face="times new roman"><br></font></div><div style="text-align: left;"><font size="3" face="times new roman">Art. 2º A aquisição de bens e serviços comuns, por todos os órgãos e entidades da Administração Municipal Direta e Indireta, nas hipóteses de dispensa de licitação, previstas no inciso II, do art. 24, da Lei Federal nº 8.666, de 21 de junho de 1993, será realizada, obrigatoriamente, de forma eletrônica, por meio da ferramenta “Licitações-e”.&nbsp;</font></div><div style="text-align: left;"><font size="3" face="times new roman"><br></font></div><div style="text-align: left;"><font size="3" face="times new roman">Art. 3º Todas as fases do procedimento licitatório e da dispensa de licitação deverão ser realizadas no sistema eletrônico, sem prejuízo da formalização e registro em processo administrativo e da publicação dos respectivos atos no Diário Oficial do Município - DOM.</font></div><div style="text-align: left;">< .....
```

Comment: Are you trying to escape or un-escape the html?

Comment: I would like to render it as normal html file. The file is suppose to be a formated html page. With web page content :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `DOMParser`:

```js
var str = '&lt;blockquote&gt;Quote&lt;/blockquote&gt;';
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
var html = doc.documentElement.textContent;
console.log(html);
document.write(html);
```

Replace `str` with the String you wish to decode.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your file are escaped. What should be `<blockquote>` in your file is `&lt;blockquote&rt;`. You should unescape that. Open the file in the browser normally and copy everything (Ctrl+A Ctrl+C). Paste it into your .html file. It should render properly now.

Comment: That is working, but  how would I do it automatically? I need to render this inside a react component, I get this text from a database...